# concatenating/appending strings in TCL

Tags: string, tcl

I am trying to append a file name to a project directory in TCL:

```
set filename hello
set currentPath "D:/TEMP/project name/subfolder/"
puts [append $currentPath $filename]
```

According to the [docs](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1031) all that is needed is a `varName` to which we are appending and a `?value` which is getting appended to `varName`. Unfortunately when I run the above code I only get `hello` as output. How can I perform this simple task on TCL?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using the variable *value* where you need the variable *name*. In Tcl (as opposed to some other languages), the `$` means “read this variable *now*” and that's meaning that you're giving a rather odd variable name to `append`. Try switching from:

```
puts [append $currentPath $filename]
```

to:

```
puts [append currentPath $filename]
# Be aware that this *updates* the currentPath variable
```

Also, if you're using this to make a filename, do consider using `file join` instead; it handles all sorts of tricky cases you're not currently aware of so that you don't ever need to become aware of them.

```
puts [file join $currentPath $filename]
```